# R building df in loop pulling out pvalues

Tags: r

I am trying to loop through a dataframe performing anova .
There seems to be an error with my loop as at the end I am only left with the value after the first iteration (i=0).  I I have tried stepping through "manually' inside the loop, i=0, i=1 and it seems to be working but when I run the whole loop and then look at the dataframe there is only the results from the first iteration.

```
sum_tab.sig<-data.frame(Df=as.numeric(),Sum.Sq=as.numeric(),Mean.Sq=as.numeric(),Fval=as.numeric(),Pval=as.numeric(),OTU=as.character())
for (i in 0:ncol(b_Genus_abund)) {
aov.ex <- aov(b_Genus_abund[,5+i]~b_Genus_abund$Location*b_Genus_abund$Bean*b_Genus_abund$Fungi*b_Genus_abund$Insect)
  ## summary of the anova given as a list
  sum_tab<-summary(aov.ex)[[1]]
  temp.sig<-sum_tab[sum_tab[,"Pr(>F)"]<0.1,]  
  temp.sig<-transform(temp.sig,OTU=colnames(b_Genus_abund)[5+i])
  sum_tab.sig<-rbind(sum_tab.sig,temp.sig)
  sum_tab.sig<-sum_tab.sig[!is.na(sum_tab.sig[,1]),]
  return(sum_tab.sig)
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A for loop does not `return` because it's not a function, so your code will basically not work and will error after the first iteration.  Try it without the return statement:

```
for (i in 0:ncol(b_Genus_abund)) {
aov.ex <- aov(b_Genus_abund[,5+i]~b_Genus_abund$Location*b_Genus_abund$Bean*b_Genus_abund$Fungi*b_Genus_abund$Insect)
  ## summary of the anova given as a list
  sum_tab<-summary(aov.ex)[[1]]
  temp.sig<-sum_tab[sum_tab[,"Pr(>F)"]<0.1,]  
  temp.sig<-transform(temp.sig,OTU=colnames(b_Genus_abund)[5+i])
  sum_tab.sig<-rbind(sum_tab.sig,temp.sig)
  sum_tab.sig<-sum_tab.sig[!is.na(sum_tab.sig[,1]),]
}
```